# Always equal-width column in table boostrap 5 and Angular

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

In my angular application using boostrap 5, i Have got a table like this

```
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th [ngClass]="{'d-none':prop1==0}"></th>
    <th [ngClass]="{'d-none':prop2==0}"></th>
    <th [ngClass]="{'d-none':prop3==0}"></th>
    <th [ngClass]="{'d-none':prop4==0}"></th>
    <th [ngClass]="{'d-none':prop5==0}"></th>
  <tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <tr>
   <td [ngClass]="{'d-none':prop1==0}"></td>
   <td [ngClass]="{'d-none':prop2==0}"></td>
   <td [ngClass]="{'d-none':prop3==0}"></td>
   <td [ngClass]="{'d-none':prop4==0}"></td>
   <td [ngClass]="{'d-none':prop5==0}"></td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Here as you can see in the markup, its a table with which the columns are hiding based on some values.

my requirement is all the columns needs to be in equal-width doesn't matter a column is hidden.

Thats is something I can accomplish using css like

```
th{
width:20%;
}
```

and it will work for the basic situation. But if one column hidden, things gonna be wrong.

So is there is anyway in boostrap to make all table columns always same width?

If its a grid system, its simple using row and col

```
<div class='row'>
   <div class='col'></div>
   <div class='col'></div>
   <div class='col'></div>
   <div class='col'></div>
   <div class='col'></div>
</div>
```

I am expecting something similar to it. I tried a luck by speicifying class row to **tr** and **col** to each th, doesnt helped me.

Please share your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

If you hide a **th** or **td**, you break the layout of the **table** since the sum of width of them all is not **100%** anymore.

To achieve this, you should use an element in each one of the **th** and **td** and hide that instead. To do so, you keep the layout as it is.

```css
th {
  width: 20%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        <span [ngClass]="{'d-none':prop1==0}"></span>
      </th>
      .....
      <tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span [ngClass]="{'d-none':prop1==0}"></span>
      </td>
      .....
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks.. No I am not hiding a header alone. If I hide a header the same data column also will hide